# Unrecognised selector for category method, Works well while debugging

Tags: ios, debugging, frameworks, categories

I have my own framework which contains a number of categories, I am using this framework in my application.
Everything works well when device is connected to the debugger, but when its not connected to debugger my application crashes with reason "Unrecognised selector sent". Basically, it fails to call a method defined in the category.
I don't know whats difference between running with debugger and running without debugger. I have found below solution after doing some google but none of them worked.

1. Use -all_load
2. Use -force_load
3. Create dummy empty classes of category.

I am using Xcode 8.1, can someone help me out?

Crash logs:

> Dec 27 14:16:16 iPhone SD(CoreFoundation)[3305] : -[TP_Util
>   containsResource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702d4dd0
>   Dec 27 14:16:16 iPhone SD(CoreFoundation)[3305] : ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TP_Util
>   containsResourceWithLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1702d4dd0'

Comment: provide error log which prints on Xcode output window...

Comment: @jayantrawat , i ahave added logs.

Comment: its difficult to understand problem from logs..hv u tried creating exception breakpoint to know at which line in code it is failing?